# Displays function after break

Tags: c++, function, output, display

So I have been tasked to create a basic hotel management system. While I'm overall happy with my work, I have realize that after I input more than 2 data at function user(), selecting break after start() will somehow call the update() function while it should be exitting the program. I have included the whole code as I have no exact idea where the problem lies.  Please help

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <fstream>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 using namespace std;

 void start();
 void admin();
 void user();
 void update();
 void display();
 void input();
 void data();
 void header();
 void slogan();
 int x=15,y=15;
 int num1,num2,num3,num4;
 int p=x, q=y;
 int f,h,k;

 ofstream file;
 string customer;
 ifstream inputFile;
 string inventory;

struct Info
{
string Name;
string idNum;
string contact;
Info*link;
 }
*head, *tail;


 int main()
{
header();
return 0;
 }

    void header()
{


cout<<"\n\t\t    ##               ##   ########   ##         #######    #######    ###       ###   ########    ";
cout<<"\n\t\t     ##             ##    ##         ##        ##         ##     ##   ####     ####   ##          ";
cout<<"\n\t\t      ##           ##     ##         ##        ##         ##     ##   ## ##   ## ##   ##          ";
cout<<"\n\t\t       ##    #    ##      #######    ##        ##         ##     ##   ##  ## ##  ##   #######     ";
cout<<"\n\t\t        ##  ###  ##       ##         ##        ##         ##     ##   ##   ###   ##   ##          ";
cout<<"\n\t\t         #### ####        ##         ##        ##         ##     ##   ##         ##   ##          ";
cout<<"\n\t\t          ##   ##         ########   ########   #######    #######    ##         ##   ########    \n";


cout<<"\n\t\t            ########    #######       ##    ##    ######    ########   ########   ##      ";
cout<<"\n\t\t               ##      ##     ##      ##    ##   ##    ##      ##      ##         ##      ";
cout<<"\n\t\t               ##      ##     ##      ##    ##   ##    ##      ##      ##         ##      ";
cout<<"\n\t\t               ##      ##     ##      ########   ##    ##      ##      #######    ##      ";
cout<<"\n\t\t               ##      ##     ##      ##    ##   ##    ##      ##      ##         ##      ";
cout<<"\n\t\t               ##      ##     ##      ##    ##   ##    ##      ##      ##         ##      ";
cout<<"\n\t\t               ##       #######       ##    ##    ######       ##      ########   ########\n";

cout<<"\n\t\t  #######    ######    ##         ##   ########    ######    #######     ###     ##   ##    ###### ";
cout<<"\n\t\t ##         ##    ##   ##         ##   ##         ##    ##   ##    ##    ####    ##   ##   ##    ##";
cout<<"\n\t\t ##         ##    ##   ##         ##   ##         ##    ##   ##    ##    ## ##   ##   ##   ##    ##";
cout<<"\n\t\t ##         ##    ##   ##         ##   #######    ##    ##   #######     ##  ##  ##   ##   ##    ##";
cout<<"\n\t\t ##         ########   ##         ##   ##         ##    ##   ##   ##     ##   ## ##   ##   ########";
cout<<"\n\t\t ##         ##    ##   ##         ##   ##         ##    ##   ##    ##    ##    ####   ##   ##    ##";
cout<<"\n\t\t  #######   ##    ##   ########   ##   ##          ######    ##     ##   ##     ###   ##   ##    ##\n\n\n";
cout<<"\n\t\t****************************************************************************************************\n\n\n\n\n";


system("pause");
start();

     }

  void start()
       {
 int choose;
system("cls");
slogan();
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tWELCOME \n\n\n";
cout<<"[1].ADMIN \n\n";
cout<<"[2].USER \n\n";
cout<<"[3].EXIT \n\n";
cout<<"SELECTION : ";

   cin>>choose;

switch(choose)
{
    case 1:
    system("cls");
    admin();
    break;

    case 2:
    system("cls");
    user();
    break;

    case 3://the problem lies here, where it should exit the program//
    cout <<"THANK YOU FOR USING THE PROGRAM"<<endl;
    slogan();
    system("cls");
    break

    default:
    system("cls");
    start();
}
  }

    void slogan()
   {



cout<<"\n\t\t\t\tHOTEL CALIFORNIA\n";
cout<<"\t\t\t-------------------------------\n";
cout<<"\t\t\t\tHEAVEN ON EARTH\n\n";


   void admin()
      {
  system("cls");
  slogan();
  cout<<"\n\n\n\t[1].ROOM AVAILABLE\n\n";
  cout<<"\t[2].ONLINE VIEW\n\n";
  cout<<"\t[3].WALK IN\n\n";
  cout<<"\t[4].BACK\n\n";
  cout<<"\tSELECTION : ";
  cin>>num2;

   switch(num2)
{
    case 1:
    system("cls");
    k=p+q;
    if (k==0){

    cout << "SORRY OUR ROOMS ARE FULL hRIGHT NOW"<< endl;

    cout << "PLEASE COME BACK LATER"<< endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        start();


    }
    cout << "Room available " << k << endl;
    cout << "Small: " << p << endl;
    cout << "Large: " << q << endl;


    system("pause");
    admin();


    case 2:
    system("cls");
    display();
    break;

    case 3:
    system("cls");
    input();
    break;

    case 4:
    system("cls");
    start();
    break;

    default:
    system("cls");
    start();
  }
  }


    void input()
    {
      cout<<"\n\nPLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME: ";
  cin>>std::ws;
  getline( cin, customer );
  customer += ".txt";
  file.open( customer.c_str() );

 system("cls");
      slogan();
   cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tCHOOSE ROOM :\n\n";

cout<< "[1].LARGE(FOR MORE THAN 3 PEOPLE)********RM200 per night"<<endl;
cout <<"[2].SMALL(FOR LESS THAN 3 PEOPLE)********RM100 per night"<<endl;
cout <<"FOR 3 PEOPLE BEST TAKE LARGE"<<endl;


cout<<"\n\n";
cin>>num3;
system("cls");

if (num3==1){
    q--;
    data();
    system("pause");
    file.close();
    start();
}else if (num3==2){

    p--;
    data();
    system("pause");
    file.close();
    start();
} else if (num3!=1 && num3!=2){

cout << "WRONG INPUT GIVEN" <<endl;
system("pause");
system("cls");
input();

}

}

void data()
 {   int date, month,store,year=2018;

struct Info*temp;

head = NULL;
tail = NULL;

    cout << "HOW MANY NIGHTS WILL YOU BE STAYING?" << endl;
    cin>>f;

    if(f>30 || f<0){

    cout << "NOT ALLOWED" <<endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    start();

    }

    h=200 * f;
    cout << "\n\nTotal: RM" << h << endl;
    file<< "Total: RM " << h ;
    system ("pause");
    system("cls");

  cout<<"\n\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\tFOR THE YEAR 2018\n";
cout<<"\t\t\t-------------------------------\n";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\tONE MONTH=30 DAYS\n\n";
cout<<"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\tENTER CHECK IN DATE(1-30)\n\n";
    cin>>date;
    if (date>30 || date<0){


        cout <<"CANNOT COMPREHEND" << endl;
           system("pause");
        admin();
    }

    cout << "\t\t\tENTER CHECK IN MONTH(1-12)" <<endl;
    cin>>month;
    if (month>12 || month <0){

        cout <<"CANNOT COMPREHEND" << endl;
         system("pause");
        admin();
    }

    file << "CHECK IN ON: " <<date<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
    store=date+f;
    if(store>30){

        store=store-30;
        month=month+1;

        if (month>12){

            month=month-12;
            year=year+1;
        }
    }
    file <<"CHECH OUT ON: " << store<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;

    Info *a=new Info;
    cout<<"ENTER NAME(SAME AS PREV)"<<endl;
    cin>>std::ws;
    getline(cin, a->Name);
    cout<<"\n";

    a->link=NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = a;
        tail = a;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->link =a;
        tail= a;
    }

    Info *b=new Info;
    cout<<"ENTER IC "<<endl;
    cin>>std::ws;
    getline(cin, b->idNum);
    cout<<"\n";

    b->link=NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = b;
        tail = b;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->link =b;
        tail= b;
    }

    Info *c=new Info;
    cout<<"ENTER PHONE NUMBER "<<endl;
    cin>>std::ws;
    getline(cin, c->contact);
    cout<<"\n\n";

    c->link=NULL;
          if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = c;
        tail = c;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->link =c;
        tail= c;
    }

    temp = head;
   while(temp!=NULL)
{
    file<<"\n"<<temp->Name;
    file<<"\n"<<temp->idNum;
    file<<"\n"<<temp->contact<<" \n\n";
    temp = temp->link;
}
 cout<<"\nDONE\n\n";

   }

   void user(){
 system("cls");
   slogan();

      cout<<"\n\n\n\t[1].REGISTER\n\n";
    cout<<"\t[2].UPDATE\n\n";
   cout<<"\t[3].BACK\n\n";
   cout<<"\t[4].EXIT\n\n";

    cout<<"\tSELECTION : ";
  cin>>num4;
     switch(num4)
{
    case 1:
    system("cls");
    cout << "Room available " << p+q << endl;
    cout << "Small: " << p << endl;
    cout << "Large: " << q << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    input();

    case 2:
    system("cls");
   update();
    break;

    case 3:
    system("cls");
    start();
    break;

    case 4:
    system("cls");
    break;

    default:
    system("cls");
    start();
    }

     }

     void display()
      {
  slogan();

      cout<<"\n\nENTER YOUR NAME : ";
      cin>>customer;
  inputFile.open((customer+".txt").c_str());

   if (inputFile)
      {

   getline(inputFile, customer);

   while (inputFile)
   {

      cout << customer << endl;

      getline(inputFile, customer);
   }


   inputFile.close();
   system("pause");
    admin();
  }
   else
  {
    cout << "NO DATA\n";
   system("pause");
   admin();
  }

   }
   void update()//instead it jumps toward here even after breaking//
{
 slogan();
 cout<<"\n\n[1] UPDATE BOOKING\n";
 cout<<"\n\n[2] CANCEL BOOKING\n";
cout<<"\n\nCHOOSE: ";
cin>>num1;
   system("cls");
      switch(num1)
   {

  case 1:

cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t---   UPDATE   ---\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\tENTER YOUR NAME TO CHECK IF DATA EXIST : ";
cin>>std::ws;
//inputFile.open((customer+".txt").c_str());
    getline( std::cin, customer );

   if(inputFile){

system("cls");
input();
break;
    }   else

{
cout<< "\n\n\t!NO DATA!" <<endl;
system("pause");
user();

}


   case 2:
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t---   CANCEL BOOKING ONLINE   ---\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\tENTER YOUR NAME : ";
cin>>customer;
inputFile.open((customer+".txt").c_str());
getline( inputFile, customer );

if(inputFile){

remove((customer + ".txt").c_str());
cout<<"\n\n\tBOOKING CANCEL";
cout<<"\n\n\tINFO DELETED\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\tBYE BYE\n\n";
system("pause");
start();
break;
   }   else

{
cout<< "\n\n\t!NO DATA!" <<endl;
system("pause");
start();

   }

default:
    system("cls");
    start();

       }
  }
```

The only related functions in my opinion is the user() and update(), since if I remove the update() function, it does not proceed to call any other function.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's really hard to make it out as-is

Comment: Please create a [mcve] or just debug your program

Comment: Can you simplify this code so it focuses on the problem? Remove all the code that is not executed as part of the scenario. Also, what did you discover when you debugged the program?

Comment: Im sorry about the indent, I will edit it soon. About minising it, I couldnt do so as I have no idea where the problme lies/

Comment: @Rookie13 _" I couldnt do so as I have no idea where the problme lies/"_ Comment as much as possible out from your code while still reproducing the same error.

Comment: @RaymondChen what do you mean by debugging. Sorry, this is my first time using C++ on large project.

Comment: The same way you debug a small project.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add a ";" on the break code at line 110